# ftplib issues not placing file

Tags: python, linux, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to use ftplib to place a file on the server but im getting some errors which I dont know what to do with. Login works but tryign to upload the file outputs errors.
This is the code that I am using :

```
import ftplib
import os

def upload(ftp, file):
    ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    if ext in (".txt", ".htm", ".html"):
        ftp.storlines("STOR " + file, open(file))
    else:
        ftp.storbinary("STOR " + file, open(file, "rb"), 1024)

ftp = ftplib.FTP("")
ftp.login("", "")

upload(ftp, "hist.txt")
```

The error log is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in upload
  File "/home/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 492, in storlines
    self.voidcmd('TYPE A')
  File "/home/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 254, in voidcmd
    return self.voidresp()
  File "/home/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 229, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "/home/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 215, in getresp
    resp = self.getmultiline()
  File "/home/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 201, in getmultiline
    line = self.getline()
  File "/home/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 191, in getline
    if not line: raise EOFError
EOFError
```

What is going on here >?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by setting a configuration which must be done before a binary file is sent.
this is the configuration:

```
ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I')
```

I hope this helps someone else too.